# httpClient connection pool manager validateAfterInactivity

Tags: java, spring, connection, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am looking at the documentation of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html

There is an API setValidateAfterInactivity. validateAfterInactivity is not very clear to me. It says - "Defines period of inactivity in milliseconds after which persistent connections must be re-validated prior to being leased to the consumer"

How exactly does it re-validate the connection? Wanted to understand the process. Does it send any http request to server or something to re-validate, or its something else?

What is the criteria/mechanism it uses to revalidate the connection? How does it all work?

Answer (score 0):

In [`org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool`](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/1f51a73277bda05839ed8b1ccd6fa97db954be35/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/pool/AbstractConnPool.java#L254):

```
if (validateAfterInactivity > 0)  {
    if (leasedEntry.getUpdated() + validateAfterInactivity <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        if (!validate(leasedEntry)) {
            leasedEntry.close();
            release(leasedEntry, false);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

And in [`org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool`](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/dd76cf91c8f9125c7e0e29770622271f9417b46d/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/conn/CPool.java#L70) or other similar implementation:

```
@Override
protected boolean validate(final CPoolEntry entry) {
    return !entry.getConnection().isStale();
}
```

Finally, `isStale` in [`org.apache.http.HttpConnection`](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/1f51a73277bda05839ed8b1ccd6fa97db954be35/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.java#L71):

```
/**
 * Checks whether this connection has gone down.
 * Network connections may get closed during some time of inactivity
 * for several reasons. The next time a read is attempted on such a
 * connection it will throw an IOException.
 * This method tries to alleviate this inconvenience by trying to
 * find out if a connection is still usable. Implementations may do
 * that by attempting a read with a very small timeout. Thus this
 * method may block for a small amount of time before returning a result.
 * It is therefore an <i>expensive</i> operation.
 *
 * @return  {@code true} if attempts to use this connection are
 *          likely to succeed, or {@code false} if they are likely
 *          to fail and this connection should be closed
 */
boolean isStale();
```

There are different implementations for `org.apache.http.HttpConnection`, they pretty much do what the doc says, either check if there is End-of-File or try to read from connection. By default the `validateAfterInactivity` is set to 2 seconds.

Note: above is referencing the httpclient library version 4.5.13.

Answer (score -2):

It use JDBC connection to do validate.

```java
                    final ManagedHttpClientConnection conn = poolEntry.getConnection();
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.activate();
                    } else {
                        poolEntry.assignConnection(connFactory.createConnection(null));
                    }
                    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        log.debug("Connection leased: " + ConnPoolSupport.formatStats(
                                poolEntry.getConnection(), route, state, pool));
                    }
```

source code [here](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/81c1bc4dc3ca5a3134c5c60e8beff08be2fd8792/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/io/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java#L301)

Comment: I don't understand, what does JDBC have to do with the question